# How to trigger destroy event in jquery file upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I have entries in table rows and all row has delete button. The data results are stored as json in db and stored in hidden input in page. I want to trigger the destroy event with that my button and the javascript will get the data stored that hidden input and delete the files from server. Than I will check the response if success I will delete my entry from database too.

I don't know how to call destroy function and load the data which will contains json file data. my code is like that for d now.

```
$('form#adminList').on('click', 'button.sil', function(){
    var row = $(this).parents('tr');
    $('.btnToggle').prop('checked',false);
    $(row).find('input:checkbox').prop('checked',true);
    $('input[name="task"]').val('delete');
    var data = JSON.parse($(row).find('span.data').text());
    //console.log(data.files);
    var nfiles = data.files.length;
    var context = $('#fileupload')[0];
    $(context).fileupload('option','destroy').call(context, $.Event('destroy'), data);

    // check the response. If it is ok do submit.
    //this.form.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the [**API documentation**](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#deinitialization) you could do it through below :

```
$(context).fileupload('destroy');
```

Hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: I may wrong about the destroy function. I need to delete the files from server and the information data which contains the data about the images which will be deleted are stored in an hidden html element. Your suggestion destroys the widget I thnik :S. Anyway thanks four your reply :)